# How to have multiple values for a single php variable?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

So my query works on the actual `phpmysql` server when I manually type in some values but in `php` I am having some difficulty.

This is my `SQL` table:

```
userID | forename | surname  |      email         | age    | 
------------------------------------------------------------
    1  |  Jack    |  Wolf    |   dj@rave.com      |  19    | 
    2  |  Mark    |  Smith   |   mark@rave.com    |  18    | 
    3  |  Ben     |  Cas     |   sex@club.com     |  21    | 
    4  |  Jos     |  Jis     |   jis@jos.com      |  19    | 
    5  |  Luke    |  Kils    |  kils@kiss.com     |  23    | 
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Basically, I want to pass in some `UserID` values like this `1,3,5` and it should display:

```
userID | forename | surname  |      email         | age    | 
------------------------------------------------------------
    1  |  Jack    |  Wolf    |   dj@rave.com      |  19    | 
    3  |  Ben     |  Cas     |   sex@club.com     |  21    | 
    5  |  Luke    |  Kils    |  kils@kiss.com     |  23    | 
------------------------------------------------------------
```

The userID values can vary depending on what the user selects so it can be `2` or even `1,2,3,4` or even `1,2,3,4,5`

This is my `php` code:

```
<?php
require "init.php";
if(!empty($_POST['userID'])){
    $userID = $_POST['userID']; 
    $stmt = "SELECT userID, forename, surname, email, age
            FROM users
            WHERE userID IN (?)";   
    $result = $conn-> prepare($stmt);
    $result->bind_param('i', $userID);
    $result->execute(); 
    $outcome=$result->get_result();
    $response = array();
    if(($outcome->num_rows)>0){
        while($row = $outcome->fetch_assoc()){
            $response[] = array
            (
                "userID" => $row["userID"],
                "forename" => $row["forename"],
                "surname" => $row["surname"],
                "email" => $row["email"],
                "age" => $row["age"]
            );
        }
    echo json_encode($response); 
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode("None found");
    }
}

?>
```

My code can't do the `userID = 1,2,3` thing, if you know what I mean. `userID` can only take at most 1 parameter but I want to input as many as I like at times.

How can I fix it?

Comment: since you didn't post your HTML form for this, we don't know if `$_POST['userID']` is treated as an array and by the looks of what you did post, it isn't. So, what results are you getting and errors if you are checking for them at all? I doubt you are. POST multi-dimensional arrays need to be imploded etc.

Comment: Well I am doing `android` development, I use `postman` to test the code. Yes, I don't know how to implode it or whatever it is

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` when you send multiple.

Comment: using `$result->bind_param('i', $userID);` suggests that you pass it a single integer value but if you pass in a comma separated set of IDs that will be a string

Comment: @RamRaider exactly that, but I don't know how to do that. please could you modify my code

Comment: You could just ignore the only piece of info that is needed to answer.

Comment: @AbraCadaver but how do I apply it to this context? Sometimes `UserID` can take 1 value sometimes it can take 3

Comment: @LukazsPioetrszci Apparently, you are posting not multiple values, but only a single-character string to your PHP. You are probably having difficulty in collecting the values before posting. We need to see the related parts from HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: @ArmanOzak I am not using `HTML` or `JavaScript`. I am doing `Android` development and only need `php` to get values from my server in the form of `JSON`

Comment: Ok, then you are not posting multiple user id values from the Android application to the PHP, because the posted value is a single character.

Comment: I know I am testing my stuff with `Postman` right now

Answer (score 0):

[preview of form and table in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TaMy.png)

Ok @Lukazs Pioetrszci i got you, 
on the font end you need the query result 
on the back end you need a custom Query based on available table date

```
   <?php
require "init.php";

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "masterHQ";
$password = "mein1234";
$mySelected = $_POST['selectedID'];
$myWho = $_POST['who'];
$clearMe = $_POST['clear'];

//$SelectTable = "SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `userID` ASC";
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'masterHQ', 'mein1234', 'test_me');
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
        }
        echo "<br />";
        $tally = count($myWho);
echo $tally . " count results";
            foreach ($myWho as $Who) {
                $fromList .= "`userID` = "." ". $Who . " ";
                $tally--;
                if($tally > 0){
                    $fromList .= " OR"." ";
                }
            }
$SelectThis = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE " . $fromList . "ORDER BY `userID` ASC ";
$joe = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `userID` = 1 OR `userID` = 2 OR `userID` = 3 ORDER BY `userID` ASC" ;
echo  "<br />";
if ($clearMe == 'clear'){
    $SelectThis = "SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `userID` ASC";
    $clearMe == '';
}   
echo "check selected sql query: " . $SelectThis;    // more error checking of custom query 
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $SelectThis )) {
    /* bind parameters for markers */
    echo "<br /> param pass<br />";
    /* execute query */
    $result=$stmt->execute();
    echo "<br /> execute pass<br />"; // error check    
    //$outcome=$result->get_result();
    /* Store the result (to get properties) */
    $stmt->store_result(); 
    /* Get the number of rows */
    echo "store pass" ;  // error check
    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($userID, $name, $last, $email, $age );
    echo "<br /> result pass <br />"; // error check results
    ?>
        <form action="answerdb_Lukazs.php" method="post">
            <table border="1px"  width="80%"> 
            <th>Selected ID</th><th>ID</th>    <th>Name</th>    <th>last</th> <th>email</th><th>age</th>
           <?php 
           while( $stmt->fetch()){
            echo '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="who[]" value="' . $userID . '" checked> ' . $userID . '</td>';
                //printf("%s is in district %s\n", $userID, $City, $District);
            echo  " <td>" . $userID . "</td> <td>"  . $name . "</td><td> " . $last . "</td><td> " . $email . "</td><td> " . $age . "</td></tr>";
                   }
                    // echo "<br /> fetch <br />";
                    /* close statement */
                        $stmt->close();
            }
            else {
                    echo "Exit Query"; // query fail
                }
                ?>
</tr></table> 
<?php
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>

<input type="submit" value="Remove ID"/>
</form> 
<form action="answerdb_Lukazs.php"  method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="clear" value="clear">
  <input type="submit" value="Show All"/>
</form>
```

Comment: or do a UserID in (x,y,z) but yeah. Nice Job. Hope it helps him

Comment: Thanks @Drew, we are all looking to get better, right? helps us both I had to puzzle through this one.

Comment: Let me know if I can help :p